# W530 separate microphone/headphone input/output

Tags: thinkpad

I have a W530 Thinkpad. Is it possible to separate the microphone input and sound output? I am using a Apple earphones and it has a built in mic. Can I disable microphone input and enable the one on the laptop but still have the earphones plugged in?

Comment: Actually, the sound driver may have the option to treat internal and external mic/speaker separately. You can check the control panel of your sound card driver. Enable expert mode if there is one since the option may be hidden by default..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Its a bit of a workaround but assuming it has a trrs/combo connector you could get a connector that splits TRRS -> 2x TRS, and just use the headphone side

[image]

I got the reverse of this with my creative earbuds (2x male trs, 1x female trrs) but both configurations should work.

Answer (score 2):

Not inherently.

You'd need a headset/mic combo that came pre-split, but combined to the one adapter, which is hard to find.

You're better off buying a USB mic and USB set of speakers.

Answer (score 0):

Another suggestion is to get a bluetooth headset (in fact, if you have one for your cell, that'll work too), and configure (the sound mixer in windows) the input from the bluetooth microphone on the headset.

Additionally, if you have the need to microphone only in an office setting, you can get a docking port for about $100-150 (second hand on ebay).  These have separate microphone and output settings.

I personally have both setups, depending if in the office or on the road.

At the office I have a wired headset with separate jacks for the mic/headphones permanently plugged into the docking station, and the mic come from there.  If listening to music via the external speakers, I plug these into the laptop output jack, which supercedes the headphone setup.  When on a call, I unplug the external speakers and the combo mic/phones headset (plugged into the docking station) comes into effect 100%.